# How does wishfi inject code on a loading page

Tags: html

Anybody knows how wishfi injects advert code into a loading page?

[wishfi](http://www.wishfi.com)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it took me a while to figure out what your question is. The answer is pretty trivial, they cheat. This is pretty horrible stuff IMHO actually. However, in order to do this the network provider, be it an ISP (very bad) or WiFi hotspot provider etc would purchase this gateway device. It does this through firmware. Now, it is pretty easy to imagine how this would be done through firmware. All you'd have to do is intercept the incoming HTTP stream, see if it is from the site you want to vandalize (yes, vandalize) and then modify the stream (i.e. insert HTML and so forth) and then send it back downstream.

http://www.arcticstartup.com/2008/12/02/wishfi-deliveres-messages-into-the-browser/